# Can I register custom functions in Jasonpath in python?

Tags: python-3.x, jsonpath, jsonpath-ng

I want to create a custom function in Jsonpath, For example, I have a JSON like below:

```
[
  {
   'name':'/home/user/Desktop/test.txt',
   'executable': True,
   'binary': False,
   'type':'file'
  }
]
```

I Want to get the content of a file in the path `/home/user/Desktop/test.txt` based on its name in JSON. For example, the query is
`$.[1].content()`

Can I register a function in jasonpath python?

Comment: Doesn't the documentation of JSONPath (or Jsonpath or JsonPath or jasonpath or Jasonpath??!) tell you if you can do this or not?

Comment: Can't you just pass that file path obtained from jsonpath to your content function as an argument? Why do you need it to follow the format you've described?